# What is the highest pulse rate possible using PIC12F683 measuring the period of a square wave

Tags: pic

What is the highest pulse rate possible using PIC12F683 measuring the period of a square wave?  In Chapter 3 tip#1 of Microchip Tips and Tricks, it provides a great tip on how measure the period of a square wave, but I need to know then, what is the highest pulse rate possible?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, please edit your question and ask a specific question (there are no question marks in your post and you've only hinted at a question) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Fine Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41211D_.pdf) is your friend.
Since you're using the Capture-Compare Module, you'll need to look for its AC Electrical specs, and you'll find these on page 131.
There you'll find a formula for the minimum CCP1 input period. This formula tells you that it depends on the PIC's instruction clock period (Tcy) and the CCP prescaler setting (N).
Since that PIC has a maximum clock frequency of 20MHz (or a minimum instruction period of 200nSec - remember those PICs divide the oscillator frequency by 4 to get their instruction clock), the maximum frequency you should try to measure with the CCP (set to a x16 prescaler) is 25MHz (or a period of 40nSec).

Comment: Thank you for this info - after reviewing page 131, I still have a question - do you know, does the 25MHz take into account the execution of the Interrupt Service Routine?

Comment: What Interrupt Service Routine? You certainly can't be expecting to trigger an interrupt for every pulse - that's why you're using the CCP hardware to count pulses for you. You would periodically (at a *MUCH* lower rate) read the CCP counter register.